# Replicating Two Server

Tags: windows, database, web-services, replication

I was given the task of replacing two servers not just RAID but everything. Also in the event of a failure of one the ip address would automatically handle request for the active one. Can someone please tell me the hardware i would need to achieve this?

Comment: I dont know if such a venture is possible. I have not seen such a system.

Comment: This seems vague -- there are many load requirements that should be considered, including your interest in budget (e.g., cheap white-box, or commercial supported hardware)...

Comment: Sorry for being too vague. The server runs IIS, MYSQL Server, Business apps, Apache, MYSQL Server, File sharing etc. I want to be able to replicate the server basically on another and allow automatic fail over in the event of a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identical server to be mirrored and software like Doubletake should be able to meet your needs. http://www.doubletake.com/

Comment: Ok will check it out.

Comment: This would work.